When converting a PDF created with Adobe Illustrator to PNG using PDFbox, the inserted lines disappear
I would like to convert a PDF created with Adobe Illustrator to PNG, but the lines inserted in the PDF disappear when it is converted to an image.
Please tell me the measures.
The libraries used are as follows.
commons-logging-1.2
fontbox-2.0.29
jai-imageio-core-1.4.0
jai-imageio-jpeg2000-1.4.0
jbig2-imageio-3.0.4
pdfbox-2.0.29
OS windows11
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

public class PDFToImageConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java pngfrompdf.PDFToImageConverter <inputPath> <outputPath>");
            return;
        }

        String inputPath = args[0];
        String outputPath = args[1];

        File inputFile = new File(inputPath);

        if (inputFile.isDirectory()) {
            // If inputPath is a directory, process all PDF files in the directory
            processPDFsInDirectory(inputPath, outputPath);
        } else if (inputFile.isFile() && inputPath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            // If inputPath is a single PDF file, process that file
            processPDF(inputPath, outputPath);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid inputPath. Please provide a valid PDF file or directory.");
        }
    }

    private static void processPDFsInDirectory(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        File directory = new File(inputPath);
        File[] pdfFiles = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));

        if (pdfFiles != null) {
            for (File pdfFile : pdfFiles) {
                processPDF(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath(), outputPath);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No PDF files found in the specified directory: " + inputPath);
        }
    }

    private static void processPDF(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        try {
            int result = convertPDFToImage(inputPath, outputPath);
            if (result == 0) {
                System.out.println("Conversion completed successfully for: " + inputPath);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Conversion failed for: " + inputPath);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred during conversion: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static int convertPDFToImage(String inputPath, String outputPath) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        int result = 1;

        try {
            document = PDDocument.load (new File(inputPath));
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            String fileName = new File(inputPath).getName();
            int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (lastDotIndex != -1) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
            }

            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
                BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 100);

                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(outputPath + "/" + fileName  + ".png"));
                } finally {
                    image.flush();
                    System.gc();
                }
            }

            result = 0;
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

I tried the above code but the lines inserted in the PDF disappear

The current version is 2.0.31, not 2.0.29.
